# How to add global style to angular 6/7 library

Tags: css, angular, styles, angular-library

I was trying to add global styles in the same way like in angular app, but it totally does not work.

My libraries' name is **example-lib**, so I added `styles.css` to `/projects/example-lib/`. I added styles in main `angular.json` file:

```
...
"example-lib": {
  "root": "projects/example-lib",
  "sourceRoot": "projects/example-lib/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "prefix": "ngx",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/example-lib/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "projects/example-lib/ng-package.json",
        "styles": [
          "projects/example-lib/styles.css" <!-- HERE 
        ],
      },
...
```

But when I tried build library using command:

`ng build example-lib`

I got error:

```
  Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styles)
```

I guess that is the other way to add global styles in separate library. Anyone can help me?

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10869

Comment: Paths starts from `src`, please give us the structure of your project

Comment: Also, you could make a `SCSS` file and import it in the original `style.scss` of your project.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 40):

I have a workaround for this. Just create the root component of your library without view encapsulation and all its styles will be then global.

**my-library.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-my-library',
  templateUrl: './my-library.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-library.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyLibraryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**my-library.component.html**

```
<!-- html content -->
```

**my-library.component.scss**

```
@import './styles/core.scss';
```

Now your **my-library.component.scss** and **core.scss** are global

**styles/core.scss**

```
body {
    background: #333;
}
```

**core.scss** is optional, I just like to keep the root files clean.

---

**Update**: In case you want your mixins and variables too, then follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57219374/1393400).

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Do I have to wrap every library component in a `lib-my-library`?

Comment: No, the styles are global. Meaning, they apply to all elements, regardless of which component they belong to. The styles are not encapsulated because of this line `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Comment: Thanks @NeilPatrao - worked like a charm. Do you know if there is a better way now or is your workaround with empty component still the cleanest solution out there?

Comment: @NeilPatrao Ok - I did as you described above and it works like a charm for Storybook but now that I want to use  global styles from the library in the app that consumes the library, I need to put somewhere - ideally in app.component.html template the <global-styles></global-styles> component and it is really hacky. I'd rather import the .scss with library global styles into the styles.scss file in the app, but the library  styles are not exposed through library public -api

Comment: @codeepic hi, checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57219374/1393400 it has exactly the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Ok - I was already looking into your answer you pointed me to. You are most welcome for figuring this shit out. I guess, I will have to add the copy .scss step in the build like you suggest. It is really weird that the Angular team doesn't support global styles for libraries out of the box without devs having to resort to workarounds.

Comment: @NeilPatrao - just checking the info on https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries official library docs and it looks like starting with version 9 of ng-packagr you can configure the tool to automatically copy the assets. More on: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#managing-assets-in-a-library

Comment: @codeepic thanks for pointing it out, I've updated the other answer

Comment: this is a brilliant solution :)

Answer (score 15):

As **@codeepic** already pointed out, there is currently [a standard solution](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#managing-assets-in-a-library).

In **ng-package.json** add

```json
"assets": ["./styles/**/*.css"]
```

The provided paths should be the paths to your files. At the same time, they will be the paths inside your **/dist** folder.
On build, the files will be copied to **/dist**. Users of your library will be able to add them to their global styles as follows.

```css
/* styles.css */
@import url('node_modules/<your-library-name>/styles/<file-name>');
```

This way you can copy any type of files.

P.S. When used with CSS, do not forget that you can create an **index.css** file that can be imported just like `node_modules/<your-library-name>/styles`.

Comment: Its also helpful to note that you need to create the folder `assets` where your styles will be.

Comment: very good, work fine here to me,  thanks you to your help.

Comment: That sort of worked for me, but I couldn't find my library's folder under `node_modules`. I could find it under `dist`, though. Should I be concerned this approach won't be reliable? Right now my structure looks like this: `workspace/projects/myLib/src/assets/styles/core.scss` and `workspace/projects/myApp/src/styles.scss` where I import from the lib

Answer (score 4):

From [Compiling css in new Angular 6 libraries](https://medium.com/@Dor3nz/compiling-css-in-new-angular-6-libraries-26f80274d8e5):

1. install some devDependencies in our library in order to bundle the css:

   - ng-packagr
   - scss-bundle
   - ts-node
2. Create css-bundle.ts:

   ```
   import { relative } from 'path';
   import { Bundler } from 'scss-bundle';
   import { writeFile } from 'fs-extra';

   /** Bundles all SCSS files into a single file */
   async function bundleScss() {
     const { found, bundledContent, imports } = await new Bundler()
       .Bundle('./src/_theme.scss', ['./src/**/*.scss']);

     if (imports) {
       const cwd = process.cwd();

       const filesNotFound = imports
         .filter(x => !x.found)
         .map(x => relative(cwd, x.filePath));

       if (filesNotFound.length) {
         console.error(`SCSS imports failed \n\n${filesNotFound.join('\n - ')}\n`);
         throw new Error('One or more SCSS imports failed');
       }
     }

     if (found) {
       await writeFile('./dist/_theme.scss', bundledContent);
     }
   }

   bundleScss();
   ```
3. Add _theme.scss inside the /src directory of the library that actually contains and imports all the css that we want to bundle.
4. Add postbuild npm script to run the css-bundle.ts
5. Include it in the styles tag in your Application in the angular.json

Comment: Could you explain what include? > Include it in the styles tag in your Application in the angular.json

Comment: @OPV  open angular.json and go to the styles property (should be inside the build > options properties) and add it as an array item. You can check here for more info: https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-include-external-css-and-js-file-in-angular-6-angular-7

Comment: `css-bundle.ts` links are dead.

Comment: Thanks @Episodex for mentioning this. Updated the answer with the content.

Answer (score 3):

From [this issue solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10869#issuecomment-396715747)

Install `cpx` and `scss-bundle` as Dev dependencies to your `package.json`. Then add the following entries in your package.json "scripts" property:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build-mylib": "ng build mylib && npm run build-mylib-styles && npm run cp-mylib-assets",
  "build-mylib-styles": "cpx \"./projects/mylib/src/lib/style/**/*\" \"./dist/mylib/style\" && scss-bundle -e ./projects/mylib/src/lib/style/_style.scss -d ./dist/mylib/style/_styles.scss",
  "cp-mylib-assets": "cpx \"./src/assets/**/*\" \"./dist/mylib/assets\"",
  ...
}
```

Replace "mylib" with your real library name and then just run in your terminal `build-mylib`. That would compile your scss assets to your dist folder.

You use this global styles in your actual Angular project just import them in your `angular.json` file within your project settings:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "dist/my-shiny-library/_theme.scss"
],
```

(use dist if your project is in the same workspace, or node_moduled if its an imported library)

Answer (score 2):

1-  be sure you are putting your styles inside the library

example:

projects/your-lib-name/assets/styles.css

2- then in your ng-package.json   (in the lib for sure)  put the assets rule

```
    {
      "$schema": ...  , 
      "dest": ...   , 
>     "assets": [
>         "./assets/*"
>       ],
      "lib": ...
    }
```

3-
in your application, you can use this asset

```
  "styles": [
              "../your-lib-name/assets/styles.css"
            ]
```

[this is a tutorial](https://youtu.be/D9JfBOb0n08?t=538)