# How can we add a global style in angular library

Tags: angular

I created a component in angular library.
If I create a class in the `component.css` and use it in the `component.html` it works fine.
But how to use a global style in this component?
Thanks,

Comment: Use the file styles.css

Comment: From Angular 9 it's more easy, see the docs:https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#managing-assets-in-a-library

Answer (score 1):

In `angular.json` you can add your global `css` file:

```
"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [
        "src/favicon.ico",
        "src/assets"
    ],
        "styles": [
            "src/styles.css"
        ]
```

Note that there is one default `css` file named `styles.css` in root folder.

Here is working sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/global-appearance?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: am talking about adding style in angular library and not a simple angular project.

Comment: @achrafbenalaya For library follow this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377419/how-to-add-global-style-to-angular-6-7-library